# Pass FromHeader the httpClient to webapi 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Below is the code, I have used to call the api. However, May I know how to pass http header

for example
Get customer has a header [FromHeader] field.

string uri = "https://localhost:7290/customers";
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient `GetAsync()` is a shortcut for generating an instance of a `HttpRequestMessage` set to perform a GET for the specified URI and passing it to the `SendAsync()` method.

You can create your own request message instance and append additional details such as headers, then use the `SendAsync()` method yourself.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
request.Headers.Add("header", "value");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-6.0